# How can I run an Update with a Row Counter

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

When I run this, I get a running count if IDs.

```
SELECT asset_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY asset_id) AS cnt
FROM CPDG
ORDER BY asset_id
```

So, I turned that into an `Update` statement like this.

```
UPDATE CPDG
SET cnt = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY asset_id) 
           FROM CPDG)
```

But now I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I update a column with a running count?

Comment: Think about it. You're trying to set `cnt` to multiple values.

Comment: `WITH x AS (....) UPDATE CPDG SET cnt = x.cnt FROM x WHERE CDPG.asset_id = x.asset_id`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the CTE would be updatable, so you could just update the CTE, rather than performing a `JOIN` the table to itself.

Comment: @Larnu: right; not all CTEs are updatable this way and I tend to forget the exact rules.

Comment: I put the update inside the parentheses and I got this error: Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE'.

Comment: That's because the `UPDATE` doesn't belong in the parentheses. `WITH` introduces a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), the `UPDATE` statement then uses it. The only thing that can go inside a `WITH` is a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CTE with your select query and then update on that:

```
with cte as (
  select asset_id, cnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY asset_id) as rn
  from CPDG
)
update cte 
set cnt = rn
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=662f92fe05d926989e81b0f6811cec0a).

Comment: Oh no!!  Common table expressions followed by INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE are not supported in this version.  This is Azure SQL Data warehouse.  I guess I've got to some up with an alternative solution.

Comment: This works for SQL Server as it is the tag of your question.

Comment: Yes, it's correct for SQL Server.  We just switched over to DW.  The look and feel is just like SQL Server, but there are some big differences.  I just remembered what environment I'm working in now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a row_number() call ...

```
UPDATE
  CPDG a
SET
  CPDG.cnt = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM CPDG b
    WHERE a.asset_id > b.asset_id
  )
```

Comment: That's in innovative idea.  When I ran this code I got: Incorrect syntax near 'a'.  Did I miss something here?

Comment: The target of an `UPDATE` statement cannot be aliased (it can be an alias, but it cannot be aliased itself), nor are table names allowed in the `SET` clause. The outer table must be named `CPDG` and must be referred to that way.